# How can I set an icon for a link programmatically

Tags: windows, go

I created a link in Go using

```
err = os.Link(file, desktoplink)
```

is it possibile to set an icon for this link (the programm will run on Windows)?
How can I do it?

Comment: The `os.Link` function isn't doing what you think it's doing; it's creating a hard link to the file. Want you want to be doing is create a shortcut file (.lnk). This question might help you get started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32438204

Comment: Ahh crap...
Thank you :)